# How to center button in wordpress tesseract theme in mobile view

Tags: html, wordpress, css, mobile

I have a website(http://www.prinziah.com) for now I'm ok with how it looks(except you want to give me better ideas) but when I view it with a device with smaller screen like a mobile phone the buttons seem to be on the left and not at the center of the screen, I have tried to edit the settings in the admin panel but it didn't budge, I inspected element in my browser but couldn't find the css class that controls it. Please I need tips on how to center those buttons. You can see exactly what I'm talking about in the image below.
Thanks for you help.
[image]

Comment: Can you post the html and css of that navigation bar you want to center?

Comment: That is the issue, I cant locate the css what I want to center is the "click here" button.

Answer (score 0):

The fault was from the theme creators, I guess they realized their mistake and created an update. When I updated the theme my buttons went back to the centre of the page in mobile view